# Object [object Object] has no method when using bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using this **[DatePicker](http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)** and I get the following Error when trying to use it:

***TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datetimepicker'***

It gives the error on my script section which looks like this:

```
 $(function () {
        $('#StartDate').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false
        });
    });
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="StartDate" class="input-append">
                        <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" />
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

I have imported all the required libraries and my base Jquery library is 1.9.0

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just a note for future readers. I had continued problems with this library and eventually switched to [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) one instead as it works alot better with `Bootstrap` v3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this issue, i solved it by using the following HTML for my date picker.

```
<div id="StartDate" class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" />
    <span class="add-on">
    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is the following libraries that needs to be referenced.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
</script>
```

to bind the datepicker the following can be used.

```
$(function () {
  $('#StartDate').datetimepicker({
     pickTime: false
   })
   .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    TaskSubmitViewModel.TaskStartDate(ko.toJSON(ev.date).substr(1, 10))

      });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this similar problem, getting "[Object Object]", so I hope this helps you...
Have you tried changing `$('#StartDate').datetimepicker({` to `$('#StartDate').datetimepicker.val()({`?
*If* I'm right in thinking, your selecting the datepicker element, and not it's value.

Comment: Tried Changing it, But get this now: ****Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined**** and here is the code: `$('#StartDate').datetimepicker.val();`

Comment: Sorry my suggestion hasn't helped - Have you tried removing the semi-colon? Did that make a difference? I'm not sure why it's saying it's undefined as I am able to use it in the latest Jquery...

Comment: its not what OP wants